# setting google API in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

The following gem suggests [a method to provide google account API key](https://github.com/Skalar/google_distance_matrix).  While this is usually set in an initializer, the suggestion is not specific in this regard.

The statement provided leads to a noMethodError.  Preparing an initializer with

```
class MyGoogle < GoogleDistanceMatrix

  matrix.configure do |config|
```

generates `superclass must be a Class (Module given)` where, in fact, this gem is defined as a module

```
module GoogleDistanceMatrix
  VERSION = "0.4.0"
end
```

What is a proper Railsy way to address the API-key setting and correlated issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GoogleDistanceMatrix` is a module, but `Matrix` is a class within it. A class cannot inherit from a module.

To set the API keys, according to the documentation, you should create a new instance of `Matrix` class and set config option there e.g:

```
matrix = GoogleDistanceMatrix::Matrix.new

matrix.configure do |config|
  config.google_api_key = "YOUR_API_KEY"
end
```

Than you can use `matrix` instance to do further usage of the gem. Have fun!

Comment: OK.  I guess my mental model of how modules fit in is incomplete.